# How can you make Android 2.2 emulator display different language font such as Hindi/Marathi?

Tags: android, fonts, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo, hindi

I intend to show Marathi language/Hindi language when I run my app on Android emulator. Can you suggest how this may be done?

I searched the internet and found solutions such as rooting. But rooting is for Android phones and not Android emulators.

Please suggest. It is critically important.

Answer (score -2):

You dont need to root ur phone for support the Hindi or marathi.
I already used Marathi font in my app
Check below link it will help for you [Link](http://palewar.com/2012/04/how-to-use-hindi-font-in-android-app/)

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged (links tend to get stale over time).
Please consider editing your answer and adding a synopsis here.